# iText nested table - first row not rendered

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i am generating a table, based on the size of a list.
The table is set up to fit on an avery form, there are **5** columns and 13 rows.

When the list size is smaller than 5, nothing is shown.
If the list size is 5 or greater, it is shown properly.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin);   
//5 rows for the table
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

Object obj = list.get(i);
//this is the superior cell
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setFixedHeight(60.4f);

// Nested Table, table in the cell
PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(2);
nestedTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
nestedTable.setWidths(new int[] { 24, 76 });

// First Cell in nested table
PdfPCell firstCell = new PdfPCell();
// fill cell...

// second cell in nested table
PdfPCell secondCell = new PdfPCell();
// fill cell

// put both cells into the nestedTable
nestedTable.addCell(firstCell);
nestedTable.addCell(secondCell);

// put nestedTable into superior table
cell.addElement(nestedTable);
table.addCell(cell);
}

doc.add(table);
doc.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `PdfPTable` with 5 columns. iText will only write a table row to the output document when that row is complete, i.e. when it contains 5 cells. If you add less than 5 cells, the row is never flushed.

You say:
*If the list size is 5 or greater, it is shown properly.*

This is not correct. Unless the amount of cells is a multiple of 5, the last row will not be shown.

So you have to make sure there are 5 cells in the final row. You can easily do this by using this convenience method, right before adding the table to the document: `table.completeRow()`

Comment: sorry, i must have missed the uncomplete rows.
table.completeRow() is the solution, thanks again!